# When I connect my Samantha Module to my NXT, the NXT shows the wrench icon

Tags: nxt

When I connect my Samantha module to my NXT, it shows the wrench icon instead of the USB icon.

I have tried updating the firmware, to no avail.

The blue light does not turn on. It sees the WiFi network just fine, the white light flashes, but it will not connect to the NXT.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try http://thenxtstep.blogspot.com/2006/06/nxt-problems-post-problems-and.html Some of the info is a little old, but the site appears to be active.